# Efficient OCR finetuning

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am working on a project that involves OCRing an extremely large number of PDFs. Each PDF is an image of a normal, office-type document. Each PDF page is stored a separate file. Is there any way to do this faster (i.e. with lower compute time) than my current approach?

With a project this size, any small performance improvement would yield a large reduction in computing cost/time. Currently, the call to Tesseract takes about 2-3 orders of magnitude more time than all other processing steps in the project.

For each file (page.pdf), I first convert it to Tiff (image.tiff), like so. I stripped the Python off of this call for clarity.

```
ghostscript -o image.tiff -q -r300x300 -sCompression=none -sDEVICE=tiffgray page.pdf
```

Then I run essentially the following procedure.

```
def ocr( image ):
    import tesseract, cv2.cv as cv

    # Load Tesseract
    api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
    api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
    api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)

    # Load and OCR the image file 
    cv_image = cv.LoadImage(image, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    tesseract.SetCvImage(cv_image, api)

    # Return the text
    return api.GetUTF8Text()
```

I've simplified a bit for clarity. I don't actually separately load Tesseract for each file, for instance. I handle exceptions, etc. However, the differences don't really matter, since 99.9% of the time used is in the api.GetUTF8Text() call.

Any ideas to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to parallelise it, if on a multicore CPU.

Have a look at something like http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am already parallelizing the process as a whole. I am running the process in the cloud, so each pdf file gets a separate machine. I run about 100 cores at once.